# How to delete files of a directory but not the folders

Tags: java, delete-file

I have create some code that deletes all the files in a folder, the issue is while this is great, I want to be able to delete all the files in a directory but leave the folders intact, so I do not have to go into each folder and delete the files in it, this is my current code :

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Delete {

    public void DeleteFiles() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Called deleteFiles");
        File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/up617648/");

        String[] myFiles;
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            myFiles = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
                File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
                System.out.println(myFile);
                myFile.delete();
            }
            DeleteFiles2();
        }

    }
    public void DeleteFiles2() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Called deleteFiles2");
        File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/up617648/");

        String[] myFiles;
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            myFiles = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
                File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
                System.out.println(myFile);
                myFile.delete();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How could I modify my code to achieve this aim?

EDIT :

I have changed my code to :

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Delete {

    public void DeleteFiles() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Called deleteFiles");
        File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/");

        String[] myFiles;
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            myFiles = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
                File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
                System.out.println(myFile);
               if (!myFile.isDirectory()) {
                    myFile.delete();
                }
            }
            DeleteFiles2();
        }

    }
```

And while this does call all the folders, this is my console:

```
INFO: Called deleteFiles
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\web\resources\pdf\cam01342
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\web\resources\pdf\geg00061
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\web\resources\pdf\null
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\web\resources\pdf\up617648
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\web\resources\pdf\up626088
INFO: Called deleteFiles2
```

Tt does not delete the files inside these folders, how can I do this?

EDIT 3: Using recursion I am now getting a stack overflow error.

Here's my code :

```
public void DeleteFiles() {
    File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/");
    System.out.println("Called deleteFiles");
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
            DeleteFiles();
        }
    } else {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use File.isDirectory()?

Comment: do you want to delete the file recursively or just the files in the given folder, leaving files in the sub folders

Comment: i want to be able to delete all files inside a directory structure but leave the folders intact, added an edit

Answer (score 10):

Why not just do

```
if (!myFile.isDirectory()) myFile.delete();
```

instead of

```
myFile.delete();
```

?

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what i have done, but it only searches these folders but does not delete the files inside them, any ideas on how i can do this ?

Comment: @user2065929: Recursion. Have a look at Andre's answer.

Answer (score 3):

simply just use  `File.isDirectory()`.

just check whether it is file or directory. if it is file then delete it otherwise leave it

in your case

```
if (!(myFile.isDirectory()))
{
 myFile.delete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what i have done, but it only searches these folders but does not delete the files inside them, any ideas on how i can do this ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do

```
public void deleteFiles(File folder) throws IOException {
    List<File> files = folder.listFiles()
    foreach(File file: files){
        if(file.isFile()){
            file.delete();
        }else if(file.isDirecotry()) {
            deleteFiles(file)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to call `deleteFiles(new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/"))`;

Answer (score 3):

Using recursion it's very neat ;-)

```
private void deleteFiles(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory())
        for (File f : file.listFiles())
            deleteFiles(f);
    else
        file.delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks i have tried this but get a stack overflow error, could you take a look to see where i have gone wrong ?

Comment: If you tried to delete millions or billions of files it might be normal as recursion is a bit more memory consuming than a conventional approach; I called `deleteFiles (new File("C:\\Temp\\"));` and deleted 1500 files and 32 folders without any issues

Comment: ok thanks, it should only have to delete 20 files with 4 folders, but keep the folder, i shall try to see if i can get it to work

Comment: a small typo might end up in an infinite recursion (for instance if you wrote `deleteFiles(file);`) - this leads typically to a heap overflow

Comment: @user2065929: sorry, saw your edit #3 too late - that won't work, cause file is initialized _within_ the method; however, you have to provide the initial folder as a parameter and call it recursively with it's children;

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is overkill, as evidenced by the fact that a follow-up question was needed. See my answer there for a much simpler way:

[Recursive deletion causing a stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042432/recursive-deletion-causing-a-stack-overflow-error/15042642#15042642)

Comment: recursion is in many cases the simpliest way of implementation; your approach requires including an external library and finally it uses recusrsion too (check out http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.listFiles%28java.io.File%2Corg.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%2Corg.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below method.

```
public void deleteFiles(File folder) throws IOException {
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
     for(File file: files){
            if(file.isFile()){
                String fileName = file.getName();
                boolean del= file.delete();
                System.out.println(fileName + " : got deleted ? " + del);
            }else if(file.isDirectory()) {
                deleteFiles(file);
            }
        }
    }
```