# Can extract file but can't delete file

Tags: java, file, zip, delete-file

Below is my JAVA Code use for extract and delete file. The problem is when I successfully extract the zip file, then when I delete it. It just won't works.

Note:
local = my local folder
zipFile = my zip file name
The zip and txt file is download by java program from ftp server
I can manually delete from my explorer, except my program

```
public static void extract(File local, String zipFile) {

    try {
        // destination folder to extract the contents         
        String destName = local + "";      

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        ZipInputStream zis = null;
        ZipEntry zipentry;
        zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(local + "/" + zipFile));
        zipentry = zis.getNextEntry();

        while (zipentry != null) {
            // for each entry to be extracted
            String entryName = zipentry.getName();

            int n;
            FileOutputStream fos3;
            File newFile = new File(entryName);

            String directory = "/tmp/";

            // to creating the parent directories
            if (directory == null) {
                if (newFile.isDirectory()){
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                new File(destName+directory).mkdirs();
            }

            if(!zipentry.isDirectory()){ 
                System.out.println("File to be extracted....."+ entryName);
                fos3 = new FileOutputStream(destName + directory  + entryName);

                while ((n = zis.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1){
                    fos3.write(buf, 0, n);
                }
                fos3.close();
            }

            zis.closeEntry();
            zipentry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }// while
        zis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void delete(File file) {

    // Check if file is directory/folder
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        // Get all files in the folder
        File[] files=file.listFiles();

        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++) {

            // Delete each file in the folder
            delete(files[i]);
            System.out.println("Successfully delete file --> " + files[i]);
        }

        // Delete the folder
        file.delete();
    }else {
        // Delete the file if it is not a folder
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("Successfully delete file --> " + file);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
//extract
extract(local, zipFile);

File ftpClientZip = new File(local + "/" + zipFile);
File ftpClientMD5 = new File(local + "/" + txtFile);

delete(ftpClientZip);
delete(ftpClientMD5);
}
```

Comment: Is there any kind of exception?

Comment: this is just part of my code. My full program run flow is:
connect ftp -> download file -> check zip file md5 -> extract zip file -> copy extracted file to destination -> delete zip file

Comment: No... is there an error that is being thrown to the console... something like `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException...`

Comment: my eclipse just running fine. No error or exception is prompt

Answer (score 1):

The Files class provides two deletion methods.

The delete(Path) method deletes the file or throws an exception if the deletion fails. For example, if the file does not exist a NoSuchFileException is thrown. You can catch the exception to determine why the delete failed as follows:

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

The deleteIfExists(Path) method also deletes the file, but if the file does not exist, no exception is thrown. Failing silently is useful when you have multiple threads deleting files and you don't want to throw an exception just because one thread did so first.

Comment: Files.delete(path);  
"Files" is the method name?  
I copy and paste, it got error.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html its a in built class in java.lang.Object package

Comment: Refer this it has same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041971/how-to-delete-files-of-a-directory-but-not-the-folders-java

Comment: i using java compiler 1.6, is not supported

Comment: looking for alternative however for me above code worked always. and please add exception while using file.delete using try and catch statement.

Comment: just added try and catch statement. no error found also

Comment: wow! then let me try to run ur code and see what is the problem..sure some silly mistake should be there..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is a post typo or if it is an error in your code. You have duplicate delete() methods.

If that isn't the problem, I'm wondering if you are trying to create Files based on pointers from inside the zip file...

if not that I don't see a problem

Answer (score 0):

Check file / containing folder permissions.
It could be that the process that runs the java program has a read permission but does not have write permission

Comment: i check all zip file and txt file, file permission. canWrite, canRead, canExecute all true

Comment: Is there a chance there is an exception in the extract method? If so the close () will not happen and might cause this. It is a long shot but try to put the close () in finally block